# Starting with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to learn React. I am using the React docs itself to learn. So I was trying to render a Component called Comment on the screen. But nothing is getting rendered. I am not getting any error either.

I am using the template provided by the documentation itself called `create-react-app` to get a default react app and then I replaced the default App component with the Comment Component in `ReactDom.render()`. Is there something else that I am supposed to be doing?

What am I doing wrong here??

These is my code:

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

My js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

function Comment(props) {
    return (
        <div className="Comment">
            <div className="UserInfo">
                <img
                    src={props.author.imgUrl}
                    alt={props.author.name}
                />
                <div className="UserInfo-name">
                    {props.author.name}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="Comment-text">
                {props.text}
            </div>
            <div className="Comment-date">
                {props.date}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

const comment = {
    date: new Date(),
    text: 'I hope you enjoy learning React!',
    author: {
        name: 'Hello Kitty',
        imgUrl: 'http://placekitten.com/g/64/64'
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <Comment
        author={comment.author}
        text={comment.text}
        date={comment.date}
    />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: What's your HTML look like? Do you have an element with id `root` in your HTML?

Comment: I've added it to the question

Comment: You aren't including your JS file in your HTML file ;-)

Comment: `create-react-app` internally does it.. I say this because the default App component was working fine. Or did you mean something else??

Comment: You are going to need at least one JS file in your HTML file, or else nothing can possibly work.

Comment: Or does `create-react-app` do some sort of post HTML file transformation? hmm

Comment: NVM, something else is wrong too... investigating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to fix your problem:

```
function Comment(props) {
    return (
        <div className="Comment">
            <div className="UserInfo">
                <img
                    src={props.author.imgUrl}
                    alt={props.author.name}
                />
                <div className="UserInfo-name">
                    {props.author.name}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="Comment-text">
                {props.text}
            </div>
            <div className="Comment-date">
                {props.date.toString()}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

const comment = {
    date: new Date(),
    text: 'I hope you enjoy learning React!',
    author: {
        name: 'Hello Kitty',
        imgUrl: 'http://placekitten.com/g/64/64'
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <Comment
        author={comment.author}
        text={comment.text}
        date={comment.date}
    />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

All I did was turn the date object into a string in the `Comment` function.

Comment: Thanks.. it worked. But why did the rest of the information not show up? Or errors?

Comment: P.S. The way I figured out it was the date object was that I commented out sections of the JSX until I got something working, then added stuff back 1 by 1 until I figured out which part of the JSX was causing the issue. It's typically a good strategy to debug your apps. :)

Comment: Thanks for the tip

Comment: To be honest, I'm not totally sure why the Date object didn't show up, and googling around doesn't really give a lot of clues either. It appears simply that React doesn't like interpolating Date objects, and would rather have strings. The lack of any discernable error message is very strange as well. I wish I could give you a better answer!